# How can I configure minicom settings programatically?

Tags: linux, console, minicom

I am writing a script that uses minicom to automate some tasks.

In order to use minicom with the device I am accessing, I need to first hit "ctrl+a z" go into options, serial port settings, and disable hardware flow control.

However for my script, I want to automate this process, such that I do not have to do this in advance each time the script runs on a new machine.

I know I can save the setting as dl1 so this will be the default in the future from the minicom option menu.

However, I want a method to set this as the default without needing to go through these steps. Either hand an argument to the minicom command directly, or manually create the ".minirc.dfl" file with "pu rtscts           No" so this will be configured already for me.

Is there a way to do this?